# How AeroVironment's Switchblades steer their flight?

Tags: flight-controls, aircraft-physics, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I'm very intrigued with how [AeroVironment Switchblades: SW-300, and SW-600](https://www.avinc.com/tms/switchblade), steer their flight. There are plenty of images and animations and to my observation, none of the Switchblades have ailerons, elevators, or rudders. They have a vertical stabilizer and the rear wing can be considered as the horizontal stabilizer but, it seems, no control surfaces. So how do they steer their flight? do the switchblades use the [oblique wing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_wing) concept to control their flight path?

[image: SW-300]
[image: Oblique Wing Concept]

Comment: It looks like there’s some sort of aileron/flaperon on the front wings.

Comment: From the video, the larger of the two clearly has a rudder as well…

Answer (score 9):

The ailerons of the Switchblade 300 Block 10 and Block 20 version are moveable. This can be clearly seen for example in this [video](https://www.msnbc.com/rachel-maddow/watch/-switchblade-drones-included-in-new-u-s-military-aid-package-for-ukraine-135559749855), where they can be seen in their full up position. You can also make out that the ailerons are fitted with two springs  pushing them up, and two actuators pushing them down. Therefore roll control is definitely realized via these ailerons. Here is a picture of the aileron spring and actuators, taken from [this](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/2315/how-does-the-switchblade-300-drone-maneuver) thread. Note that this construction allows the deployment of the wings without a fixed link between ailerons and the actuators.

[image]

Pitch control is performed (IMO) in one of the following ways:

- Either the elevators are in reality elevons and therefore control roll **and** pitch
- Or the elevator is tilted as a whole. Therefore, the mechanism carrying the swiveling mechanism, springs and elevator wing is swiveled by an independent servomotor.

Although I cannot find a source or good photo/video to prove either one of these theories, I suspect that these are elevons. This would have the advantage of having only 2 actuators, meaning less failure points, less complexity at the cost of having less control over the aircraft which is probably acceptable.

As far as I can see, yaw control is passive.

Comment: As a control theorist, I strongly disagree. It might not make a difference for a human pilot, but it definitely reduces controlability of the system

Comment: Ok, makes sense now that I think about it.  One thing's for sure, with such an arrangement you can't use differential aileron (elevon) throw to counteract adverse yaw.  I used to run into this all the time when I did a lot of slope-soaring with radio-control models.  Guys would talk about how they were using differential elevon throw to reduce adverse yaw with their Zagi-style "flying wings".  (2 elevons were the only control surfaces.)   (ctd)

Comment: (ctd)  I kept telling them, "All you are doing is mixing in a pitch input.  It's nothing more and nothing less than deciding you are going to pull a little extra aft stick every time you make a roll input."  Usually they didn't believe me.

Comment: Yes that is true, lacking adverse yaw capability is probably the most prominent effect. But controlability is a pretty loose term. The lack of an evelope also results in a smaller control envelope which might cost you some performance. But apparently the effect is small enought that AeroViroment accepts this performance loss for lesser complexity. This is a bit odd, as I would excpect that the performance aspect would be more important...

Comment: Not wishing to get into extended discussion, might the deployment of one control surface not generate yaw?  Speaking mainly as a paraglider pilot where this is the primary method of instigating a turn, and paradoxically, owing to the low flying speed, the reverse of normal aileron behaviour (since a pg turns towards the lowered control surface).

Comment: Thiis is exactly what adverse yaw is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverse_yaw?wprov=sfla1

Comment: I've seen lots of R/C models with aileron and elevator control, no rudder, and as long as you don't slow down too much they fly pretty much like any other model.  They were fairly common back when the cost of servos was high, or 4-channel radio gear cost significantly more than 3-channel (up until the mid-1980s, give or take).

Comment: @ZeissIkon, that is true, I also flew such models, but I always wondered: These are "precision" guided munitions, right? Does it not hurt accuracy when you soly rely on passive stability around the yaw axis? Of course it would be easy enough to perform some simulations in order to answer this, but I havend done this...

Comment: @U_flow The Switchblade is a surveillance device, not a munition as such, and there's plenty of precision in knowing *where it's at*.  In my experience, you don't need rudder unless you're flying at high coefficient of lift where adverse drag is a large factor.  Get some speed on, and your aileron deflection is much smaller and adverse drag becomes negligible.  Builders/fliers also used to set up with aileron differential (more up than down) to reduce adverse yaw.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Your point about needing rudder might be true, but the switchblade drone is a loitering munition. It first observes its target before ramming itself into it (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AeroVironment_Switchblade). Thats also why it is equipped with explosives, hence my original question. But you are right, I still would like to see some analysis or simulation results to see just how much difference a moveable rudder really makes :)

Answer (score 0):

The real answer:
All controls are located in fuselage. They use two pushers in fuselage to rotate/move ailerons down. Two springs on wings move them up.

Comment: Hello Saiti, welcome to Aviation.Stackexchange, that is a nice insight, but @armando did ask about control surfaces not the actuators. However I am interested, do you have a source for this?